# AngularJS - simple routing not working

Tags: angularjs

I have a route with parameter like this

```
 var app = angular.module("myapp", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!").html5Mode(true);

            $routeProvider

            .when('/sukien', { templateUrl: '/app/views/sukien/index.html' , controller: 'eventCtrl' })
            .when('/sukien/:id', { templateUrl: function (params) { return '/app/views/sukien/index.html?id=' + params.id }, controller: 'eventCtrl' })


        }])
```

why /sukien works and /sukien/:id doesn't ? indeed, angularjs seems not to understand what it is. **"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"**

/sukien/333 => failed to work.

Comment: Just print `params` to console from your function to see what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing template url, state of your application and search parameters it seems.

The templateUrl tells angularjs where to look for the html file : it will very unlikely depend on the params.id and be set via a function, but will rather be a constant.

It has nothing to see with the url that the user sees in their browser.

For example : `'/app/views/sukien/suiken.html'`

The url the user sees will be something like :

```
.../suiken/1223445
```

And you can then access the id in your controller via $routeParams.id